# MySQL 4.0 Way to Lock All Tables Except Current Session for Intensive Alter Statements

Tags: mysql, locking, alter

I'm looking to do some conversions of database tables to utf-8, as well as add some indexes to some large tables. I'm hoping to lock the tables for all other users, but my current user when performing these operations. Is there an easy way to do this with MySQL 4.x?

I've done some googling but haven't had luck finding a lock that allows me to still alter in the current session.

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/lock-tables.html ?

Comment: Nope, that is what I used and it helps lock but didn't let me alter the tables.